# Are there other models for 2 dimensional hyperbolic geometry?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, hyperbolic-geometry

I was a bit browsing the internet for models for (2-dimensional) hyperbolic geometry.

and realised that besides the well known

- Poincare half plane model
- Poincare disk model
- Beltrami-Klein disk model
- Hyperboliod ( Weierstrass-  Minkowski- Lorentz- ) model

There are also the

- Hemisphere model (mostly used for transformations between the Poincare half plane model and the other models)

And via via I came in contact with the

- Gans Model (flattened hyperboloid model, a hyperboloid model minus the z coordinate)
  (see Gans, David . A New Model of the Hyperbolic Plane. American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 73, Issue 3, March 1966.
  or  www.d.umn.edu/cs/thesis/kedar_bhumkar_ms.pdf‎ )

This made me wonder:  are there even more models of (2-dimensional) hyperbolic geometry that I should know but  haven't heard of? (do add references)

Comment: You got the main models... I don't think I've run across any radically different ones yet.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Hubbard uses a 'belt model' in *Teichmuller Theory: Volume I*, but I don't have a copy on me at the moment.

Just for the sake of completeness --- in principle, by the Riemann mapping theorem, any simply connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$ can serve as a model of hyperbolic space.

---

Edit: I have recently learned of a parabolic model, defined by intersecting a vertical affine plane in $\mathbb{R}^{2+1}$ with the forward light cone and projectivizing. By the same method, any conic section should define a model of $\mathbb{H}^2$.

Comment: A generalization of Hubbard's "belt model" would be to take any k-dimensional totally geodesic hyperbolic subspace of hyperbolic n-dimensional space and on the normal bundle pull-back the metric via the exponential map.